# Compute integration with OpentSDB and grafana

Tags: opentsdb, grafana

I have an instant power consumption stored in OpenTSDB

I would like to compute the daily power consumption which is the integration of all the instant power consumption. This could have been done using average if all sampling interval where identical , which is not the case...

The formula would be something like this:
Daily consumption= Sum of ( (Delta T) * InstantPower ) / 24

Delta T= Time between current consumption sample and last sample
InstantPower = current power consumption sample

Is it possible to do it through OpenTSDB (or Grafana)?

Comment: What would be the formula in math terms, if you were to do this manually?

Comment: see my update @SergeiRodionov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using OpenTSDB. You are limited to the aggregation functions [listed on the documentation](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/query/aggregators.html).

Grafana does not add metric manipulation ability to OpenTSDB.

When working with time series, it is actually recommended to rather submit data as the integral (i.e. a monotinically increasing counter). OpenTSDB can then "differentiate" this using the `rate` function.

Comment: interesting tip for the "rate" function... But then when do you 'reset' it?

Comment: You have to use the `resetValue` to suppress _rate_ spikes caused by counter roll-over/reset. For more information about the _rate_ function, see the [Rate documentation](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/query/index.html#rate)